# Can you omit on or you can't omit it?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

Can you omit on or you can't omit it?

> I don't have a clue on how to do this.
>
> I don't have a clue how to do this.

I am not sure if "on" is necessary? Without "on", the last sentence sounds off, but I don't know if it's ungrammatical. Is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **on** is, in fact, *not* necessary and leaving it in makes the sentence incorrect as well as awkward. "I don't have a clue how to do this" is a perfectly fine sentence.